# How should I set up consensus for local development

Tags: substrate

I’m using **BABE/GRANDPA** consensus from the [`substrate-node-template`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) to develop a Substrate chain. For local development (i.e. running just one node to develop a dapp) this setup has a couple of issues.

- The node always needs to be recompiled with the `--release` flag or block execution exceeds the slot duration. This is expensive, especially on CI.
- It is not possible to shut down a node and restart it later. Consensus will complain about the epoch being too far apart.
- It takes at least the slot duration to receive feedback from submitted extrinsic.

Ideally, the consensus used for local development should behave like the `InstantSeal` consensus in Parity Ethereum. Is there a similar consensus for Substrate? What about Aura? Is it possible to tweak BABE/GRANDPA to mitigate the issues?

Comment: substrate node-template will very soon switch back to using Aura, which does not have some of these issues. You can see [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/3790) on how to swap them, or wait for it to get merged.

Answer (score 0):

The substrate node template was switched back to **AURA**.

So, now it will be much easier for you to deploy local testnets.

Just fetch the latest master of the substrate repository and get a fresh node template and run

```
substrate-node  --chain local --alice
```

Or if you build your own chain specification, supply an aura authority:

```
"aura": {
  "authorities": [
    "5FZWmKa4ePFfoSRj83XiCnDrsnWcdbf7886yFSnFAmQCcUJ2"
  ]
},
```